# How to get the owner of the window if its owner is set via WindowInteropHelper?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have parent window with its owner set via WindowInteropHelper.
Parent.Owner equals null in this case.
Is there any way to get the handle of the form owning the window?

I need this for dialog windows. When I try to set closed dialog window as the owner I get the exception.
Thus I want to set dialog's owner to be the owner of another dialog. But it is WinForm and DialogWindow.Owner equals null.

WinForm (via WindowInteropHelper-> WPF Parent Dialog (closed) -> WPF Child Dialog

Comment: Please add the code which demonstrates windows relationship. It is not clear from the description...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get handle of the WinForms form that owns the specific WPF Window you can use the following code:

```
IntPtr ownerFormHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow).Owner
```

To get handle of any window (WinForms or WPF) that owns the specific window (WinForms or WPF) you can use the following code:

```
IntPtr ownerHandle = WinAPI.GetWindow(handle, WinAPI.GW_OWNER);
//...
public static class WinAPI {
    public const uint GW_OWNER = 4;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);
}
```

Comment: It is quite interesting but new WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow).Handle returns zero for closed dialog window. Dialog windows are not disposed so they must have a valid handle.

Comment: Yes, I checked this. For closed windows zero is returned;

Comment: @voroninp in the most common cases the closed window has no handle at all, because it's handle was destroyed when closing... Thats why Zero is returned

Comment: @DmitriyG I though it is the case for usual forms. Dialog windows are not disposed.

Comment: I was wrong. What I'm talking about is applicable to WinForms. WPF disposes any window on close.